# PHP Input field values with a string save to mySql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problem with saving values into mysql database as input values unable to get into varables.Please help me.
My code like this

```
<td>  <?php 
  $targets = new Target();
  $alltargets = $targets-> getBranches();

  foreach($alltargets as $target){

  echo  "<tr>"; echo "<td>"; echo  $target['code']; echo "</td>"; echo "    <td>"; echo '<input type="text" value="" onKeyUp = "myFunction(this)" name="'.    $target['code'] . '" id="'. $target['code'] . '_percentage"  class="input-block-   level" autocomplete="off"  required/>'; echo "</td>"; echo "<td>"; echo '<input   type="text" value="" name="' . $target['code'] . '" id="'.$target['code'] . '_amount"  class="input-block-level" autocomplete="off"  required/>'; echo "  </td>";  echo "</tr>";
               $targets = new Target();
               $branch = $target['code'];
               $percentage = $target['code'] . '_percentage;
               $amount =  $target['code'] . '_amount;
               $targets-> saveBranchTargets( $branch, $percentage, $amount);
               $messagetoshow = "Update  Successfully";
              }

             ?>
      </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Save"/>
</div>
 </form>
  </div>
<script>
      var percentage = 0;
      function myFunction(element){
      var v1 = document.getElementById('totalamount').value;
      var v2 = element.value;
      var percentage = parseInt(v1) *  parseInt(v2) / 100;

      var idString = element.getAttribute("id");
      var amountId = idString.substr(0, idString.indexOf('_')) + '_amount';
      console.log(amountId);

         document.getElementById(amountId).value = percentage;
     }

  </script>

<?php
```

require_once('includes/MysqliDb.php');

class Target{

```
public function __construct() {

}


  public function saveBranchTargets($branch, $percentage, $amount){

        $this->branch = $branch;
        $this->percentage = $percentage;
        $this->amount = $amount;


      $db = new Mysqlidb();

      $data_branchtargets = array(

          'branch' => $this->branch,
          'percentage' => $this->percentage,
          'amount' => $this->amount,


      );
      $this->id = $db->insert('store_targets', $data_branchtargets);

    }
}
```

Data not insert into my database properly as they are not set it to variables correctly.

Comment: What is the `Target` class? Without knowing how the `saveBranchTargets()` function works the question can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

is there you not completed the single quot at

```
 $percentage = $target['code'] . '_percentage;
 $amount =  $target['code'] . '_amount;
```

try this chnaging by

```
 $percentage = $target['code'] . '_percentage';
 $amount =  $target['code'] . '_amount';
```

Let me know the further errors or problems if you got.

Comment: yes you are correct that's my mistake.thanks. but my issue is $percentage and $amount variables don't get the input values.

Comment: is you got problems in script. where you didn't get the values.?

Comment: once I print_r the variables it won't give the assigned values.

Comment: You assign $percentage with $target['code'] . '_percentage';
is that you get $target['code'] variable's value.
print $target and then check.

Comment: it works.out put comes as for example think code are abc,def,ghi then if i print $percentage out put is something like this : abc_percentage,def_percentage,ghi_percentage with this. I want to get assign values to those variables.